# Is it OK to have subsections with the same name?

Tags: thesis, writing

One chapter in my thesis is going to have the following style:

```
3.1 Topic A
3.1.1 Problem Description
3.1.2 Proposed Solution

4.1 Topic B
4.1.1 Problem Description
4.1.2 Proposed Solution
```

Is it OK to have subsections with the same name? Or should it rather be something like:

```
3.1 Topic A
3.1.1 Topic A Problem Description
3.1.2 Topic A Proposed Solution

4.1 Topic B
4.1.1 Topic B Problem Description
4.1.2 Topic B Proposed Solution
```

**Update:**

Many thanks to all for the comments and answers. I think understand now that it's more a question about the document structure than about the subsection titles.

Comment: Yes, it's ok. You can even have sections with the same name across different chapters (e.g. Introduction).

Comment: It might look a bit boring on the contents page but unless your institution says otherwise I don't see why it would be a problem. Check your institution's guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is generally no problem to have subsections with the same name. I have seen that many times in thesis and papers. However, although it is possible, it does not guarantee a good organisation of your ideas.  So perhaps that other organization may also be considered as alternatives.  For example, it may be more appropriate to define all problems that you will address in the first chapters and present the related work, and then present all the solutions (your contribution) in the remaining chapters, rather than presenting problem-solution and problem-solution. As a general advice, it may be better to also validate the thesis structure with your research advisor.

Comment: Presenting a bunch of problems, then a bunch of solutions doesn't seem like a good alternative, to me, especially if the problems are largely independent. It's much easier for the reader to flick back a couple of pages to remind themself of a definition than to skip back a few chapters. Also, it's easier to deal with one thing at a time than to try to remember all the problems before reading any of the solutions.

Comment: I think that it depends. I could see some scenarios where one way is better than the other and some other scenarios where the other one is better. Since I don't know what is the actual content of this thesis, I just suggest to consider alternative organisations.

Answer (score 11):

You typically have a great deal of freedom in deciding how to structure the presentation of your thesis.  If parallel construction is a good way to present your work, and if you aren't constrained not to by your advisor or your institution's regulations, I see no reason to prefer an overly verbose subsection title over a succinct title that happens to be the same as a subsection title in another section.